# File compresor that doesn't compress in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

I'm doing a python exercise that ask me to program a Lempel-Ziv algorithm to compress a text file. When I write the compressed file, the output file is higher than the first one. That's my code:

```
with open ("quijote.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
datab = ''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in data)
BitPos = {'':0}
PosAdded = {}
i = 0
for f in range(len(datab)):
    if datab[i:f] not in BitPos:
        BitPos[datab[i:f]] = format(i+1,'b')
        PosAdded[BitPos[datab[i:f-1]]] = datab[f-1:f] 
        i = f
maxl = len(str(format(i,'b')))
compres = ''
for pos in PosAdded:
    compres += str(pos).zfill(maxl)+PosAdded[pos]
compres = format(maxl+1,'b')+'\n'+compres
f = open('quijote3.txt','w')
f.write(compres)
f.close()
```

The input file is 2MB and the output is 9MB.

Comment: I shouldn't I know, but let me have a good laugh at that! :D

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question, or you'll be downvoted

Comment: what output do you want to get if [`data = b'abbaabbaababbaaaabaabba'`](http://www.data-compression.com/lempelziv.html)?

Comment: In theory, data i a string